# Dynamically insert file name and path for saving csv in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, arguments

I need to dynamically save my `pandas` data frame. I have successfully managed to output a CSV file with a static name using the following code:

```
export_csv = df.to_csv(r'static_name.csv', header=False , index=False)
```

But I have failed to make this work dynamically. With the code below, I expect to get a file with the name passed into `args.save_file_name` and `.csv` suffix. However, I get no result.

```
import os
import argparse
import pandas as pd

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', help="this is the file you want to open")
parser.add_argument('save_file_name', help="the name of the file you want for the output CSV")

args = parser.parse_args()
print("file name:", args.file) # checking that this worked

...

# export csv
path = os.getcwd()
export_path = path + args.save_file_name + '.csv'
export_csv = df.to_csv(path_or_buf=export_path, header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: probably the file is created in this location `os.getcwd()` try printing the path and check if file exists

Comment: @MorrisGevirtz, please, check the answer, and do not forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it in case it is helpful, or add an comment, if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

I think, that problem is in your `export_path` variable, that is not made right. The following code should do the job.

```
export_path = os.path.join(path, args.save_file_name + '.csv')
```